# Is there a choreography for Mingus' "The Black Saint and the Sinner Lady"?

Tags: jazz, dancing

One of Mingus' best known works is [The Black Saint and the Sinner Lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Saint_and_the_Sinner_Lady), which is written as a ballet.

The four tracks are even named as a choreography (of some sort):

1. "Track A – Solo Dancer"
2. "Track B – Duet Solo Dancers"
3. "Track C – Group Dancers"
4. "Mode D – Trio and Group Dancers"
   "Mode E – Single Solos and Group Dance"
   "Mode F – Group and Solo Dance"

But I've never seen any choreography for this album. Has anyone ever written one?

Comment: @mlibby I agree with Bebs, please make this an actual answer :)

Comment: That's fine, will do.  I'm not thrilled with it as an answer because (1) I know nothing about choreography and (2) the question seems to ask about "written" choreographies (as if maybe one could download a set of instructions or something, if such things exist), which is not what I found.  But whatever.  Thanks for prodding me.

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely choreographed dancing that has been done to this music (witness http://youtube.com/watch?v=4fML73zVcTg and http://youtube.com/watch?v=h3R_lTxyhdE, which I found with a Google search for 'mingus "the black saint and the sinner lady" choreography'), so that's an existence proof that someone probably wrote out a choreography.

Are you perhaps asking if such a choreography has been published (like as a set of written instructions or something), such that you can get your hands on a copy?  If so, sorry: I don't know how to find such a thing.